# How to get jobid inside derived BackgroundJob class?

Tags: c#, background, jobs, aspnetboilerplate

How to get current job id inside derived class of `BackgroundJob`?
In constructor or `Execute` method.
Any way.

**Update1**

I'm adding background job another way. The approach that suggested on ASP.NET Boilerplate documentation. Like this:

```
await _backgroundJobManager.EnqueueAsync<ImportContactListJob, ImportContactListJobArgs>(
        new ImportContactListJobArgs(){someargs});
```

Then my method starts from overriding method `Execute` in `BackgroundJob` inheritance class.

```
public override void Execute(ImportContactListJobArgs args)  { 
    // job here
}
```

I can't pass `null` value in `EnqueueAsync` because there is no overloaded method for this.

Comment: as far as I know there's no built-in way of doing this. create an issue on https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues

Comment: I don’t remember how exactly we solved that problem already. I quit from that project.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way of doing this.

But you can use ABP's [Hangfire Integration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Hangfire-Integration) and do [this](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/use-hangfire-job-id-in-the-code/2621/3):

> For achieving your goal, just add `PerformContext` to your job method:
>
> ```
> public void SendEmail(string name, PerformContext context)
> {
>    string jobId = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
> }
> ```
>
> And pass `null` for it when enqueuing a job:
>
> ```
> BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SendEmail(name, null));
> ```
>
> It will be substituted with a correct context when the job is actually performed.

## Update

> I can't pass null value in EnqueueAsync because there is no overloaded method for this.

Put `PerformContext` in the constructor of `ImportContactListJob`.

Related: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4444

Comment: Hi, I know this is old, but where is this placed in the constructor? Strictly in the body or in the parameter list, as an injected dependency?

Comment: @user919426 I do not have a working example. Please try it and let us know.