# Is it possible to access to current background job info in job's Execute method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

How it possible to access to current background job object in job's execute method in **aspnetboilerplate** project template?
for example property like TryCount, CreationTime

Comment: @aaron anybody?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get jobid inside derived BackgroundJob class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47626972/8601760)